# Local user created as a child object of another user

Tags: .net, active-directory

We have a domain, `sfb-ber`, an user in this domain, `sfb-ber\sfb`, with the `samAccountName` `sfb`, and a machine in this domain, `sfb.sfb-ber.local`, with the `samAccountName` `sfb$`. I'm trying to create a local user on this machine, using the following code:

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(context, "testusr", "testpwd", true);
userPrincipal.Save();

var entry = (DirectoryEntry)userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", entry.SchemaEntry.Name, entry.Path);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", entry.Parent.SchemaEntry.Name, entry.Parent.Path);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", entry.Parent.Parent.SchemaEntry.Name, entry.Parent.Parent.Path);
```

The user is created successfully, however, the code prints out the following:

```
User WinNT://SFB-BER/SFB/testusr
User WinNT://SFB-BER/SFB
Domain WinNT://SFB-BER
```

The user seems to be created as a child object of the existing `sfb` user, not the `sfb.sfb-ber.local` computer. This causes problems when trying to delete the user programmatically, later. How can I prevent this, without renaming the machine?

**Edit:** In the end, we chose not to create the user programmatically, but document this edge case and ask the system administrator to do it manually instead. I'd still like to know how to solve this issue, so I'll assign a new bounty as soon as I get more rep.

Comment: "How can I prevent this, without hardcoding the name of the machine (which might change in the future)?"   If you know how to do it when you hardcode the machine name, how about using System.Environment.MachineName to get the name of the machine instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: Using `new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, Environment.MachineName)` gives the same result as just calling `new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Domain level context and not the machine:

```
using(var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
  using(var up = new UserPrincipal(pc))
  {
    up.SamAccountName = username;
    up.EmailAddress = email;
    up.SetPassword(password);
    up.Enabled = true;
    up.ExpirePasswordNow();
    up.Save();
  }
}
```

Comment: This creates the user in the domain, not on the local machine, and it's not really what I need. Thank you, though.